# Returning seq from if/else

Tags: scala

A hypothetical example below -

```scala
val subjects = Seq("Physics","Maths","English","Chemistry")  
val books = Seq("Physics", "English")

val registeredsubjects = subjects.map{ case( subject) =>
If(books.contains(subject))
   SubjectPack(subject)
else None}.toseq
```

This code will not compile owing to the `else` part.

The intention is to create a sequence of `SubjectPack` for every subject that exists in books.

How do I make this happen?

Answer (score 2):

*This is a good example of why Scala's standard library is great IMHO!*

You have roughly 3 possible options:

**1/** the "naive" approach with `map` + `filter`. Don't use it. It's just to demonstrate the "mental path".

```scala
val registeredsubjects = subjects
  .map { case subject =>
    if (books.contains(subject)) Some(SubjectPack(subject))
    else None
  }
  .filter(_.isDefined)
  .map(_.get) // safe thanks to the filter above
```

**2/ Use `collect`**. When you see `map`+`filter` you need to tell yourself that `filter` can likely replace the 2 operations in a single.

```scala
val registeredsubjects = subjects
  .map { case subject =>
    if (books.contains(subject)) Some(SubjectPack(subject))
    else None
  }
  .collect { case Some(pack) => pack }
```

But you can actually even merge in the first `map` by moving the condition in the matching:

```scala
val registeredsubjects = subjects
  .collect { case subject if (books.contains(subject)) =>
    SubjectPack(subject)
  }
```

**3/** Finally, you can benefit from the fact that an `Option` is also a `Seq` (of zero or 1 item) and use **`flatMap`**:

```scala
val registeredsubjects = subjects
  .flatMap { case subject =>
    if (books.contains(subject)) Some(SubjectPack(subject))
    else None
  }
```

---

Choosing between 2 and 3 is often related to the complexity of the condition(s).

Comment: 4/ As the other answer says (not sure how I missed it!) Is to use `filter`+ `map`. Dropping the `if` entirely.

Answer (score 2):

The other, detailed and elaborate, answer notwithstanding, here is another option, that I think fits your case the most.

Since the question you are asking is

> The intention is to create a sequence of SubjectPack for every subject that exists in books.

It's best to try and answer it directly:

```
subjects.filter(books.toSet).map(SubjectPack.apply)
```

Chaining calls like this may seem a little wasteful, especially if there are many of them and/or the collection is huge, because each call to `filter`/`map` etc. here creates a new copy of a collection.

The way around it (again, when the collection is very large and/or the chain is rather long, in this case, it would really be an overkill) is using `iterator`, to transform the collection lazily and only create one final copy at the end:

```
subjects
  .iterator
  .filter(books.toSet)
  .map(SubjectPack.apply)
  .toSeq
```

In general, `if/else`, while isn't nearly as "bad" as, say, a `var` or  an `Option.get`, still, I think, is better to avoid in cases when it can be done without excessive "detour": branching your code makes it less readable, forcing the reader to "jump" back and forth between the branches and breaking "the flow" (even if only momentarily, like in your case, but it quickly gets much worth as the number of line in either clause increases).

Comment: A couple of things. First, as of `2.13` you should prefer `view` over `iterator` for this case. Second, one must be very cautious about adding or not `view`, since laziness also has some performance costs and it is somewhat common to just let the garbage collector do its work to be better. Finally, not sure, but I think the `toSet` here is evaluated per element which is probably way worse than the traversals.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I "should"? Nah ... I don't wanna :D If you are going to convince me I "should" do something, you are going to have to start with the "why". And the reasoning like "some guy with glasses said it in a conference" is not going to suffice. "Be very cautious about adding view" – Yeah, that's one of the reasons why I believe that I exactly should NOT prefer it over iterator. Garbage collector doing work is not not the only (nor the main) concern, a bigger one is cost of copying.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez and yes, `.toSet` is definitely NOT evaluated per element, because the argument to `filter` is a _function_.

Comment: About preferring `views`. They are safer than `Iterators` since they allow reuse and have more operations than those, like `groupBy`. This is why they are generally preferred for this use case of chaining operations. But sure, the word _"should"_ means is just an advice, no need to follow it. About performance. `Iterator` should not be more efficient than `View` in most situations, since the latter usually just delegates to the first.

Comment: The point is that according to folks like Rex, who worked on the stdlib and usually work on performance-sensitive code, using `view` / `iterator` does not necessarily increase performance. Of course, as with any performance advice, yeah just doing what _"some guy (with glasses?) said it in Discord"_ blindly is a bad idea, once should benchmark and all that stuff _(this is what I meant by being cautious)_. But, I personally would default to just not complicating the code without evidence of gains.

Comment: Finally, yeah you are correct about the `toSet` being evaluated once since `Sets` are functions. This is, however, one of those tiny details that one tends to forget when reading code. Personally, I would move the `toSet` out for my own mental tranquility. But that is just me, if you _(here referring to anyone)_ feel like they wouldn't forget about it and had to double check in the future then great since it saves an intermediate variable.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez 
Re "safer because they allow reuse": that is actually _less_ safe in my book (and pretty much the reason why I prefer iterators), because it brings up all the performance considerations you (rightfully) mentioned earlier, and are in general less transparent and more "mystical" in behavior.  Re. "advice": paraphrasing Sagan, unsolicited advice requires extraordinary proof ;)  
Re. "iterator should not be more efficient than view": I don't see how that can be the case seeing how a view is reusable and iterator is not. Consider iterating over an infinite stream ...

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez re. "doesn't necessarily increase performance": I am sure, there are some convoluted corner cases when it doesn't. But in general, I have hard time imagining how iterating over something may be not be faster than iterating PLUS copying it. I also do not think that adding `.iterator` and `toSeq` to a transformation chain qualifies as "complicating the code"

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Re. "toSet": I don't know who are those people who "tend to forget" that `.filter` takes a function ... but I'd argue that until they gather more adequate experience, they'd actually _benefit_ from seeing things written this way: after, perhaps, having to doublecheck a few times, they will get into a habit of _reasoning_ about the code rather than just  _reading_ the characters that comprise it, which is quite beneficial if you ask me.

Comment: You know what, you are right. I will refrain from giving unsolicited advice to someone way smarter than me, like you _(despite the reading comprehension issues)_. Hope you have a great day.